# ToolBar home button direction

Tags: android, android-toolbar

i have an activity that contains a `ToolBar` and i'm setting the `ToolBar` using the following code

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

The problem is my application containing two languages and when i switch language from English to Arabic and then start the previous activity the direction of the home button is reversed to right like this

[image]

So my question is how to force English localization for this button

Answer (score 0):

in your style xml put this line of code

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_arrow_left</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Arabic language is read from right to left. The arrow is set properly, only thing you need to do is provide RTL support to your app.

To provide RTL support, specifically, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.